# Is there a way to use latex packages in markdown file?

Tags: latex3, markdown, rmarkdown

I'm trying to use the 'actuarialangle' code but it doesn't work in markdown file, it just works when i use Rmarkdown file...

```
---
title: "Using more LaTeX packages"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["actuarialangle"]
---
<!-- tinytex::install_tinytex() -->
$$
\actuarialangle{n}
$$
```

Comment: markdown itself has no connection to latex. Are you asking about a system that converts to latex (like rdoc), or a system that uses latex emulation such as mathjax in generated html (like markdown on math stackexchange or github)

Answer (score 1):

You said it. A way is use  Rstudio, that use LateX to convert this in a PDF. But note that the  export to LateX is made really by   `pandoc`.

If you export to LaTeX directly using pandoc alone,  from a terminal (or an editor able to run external commands) in this way:

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -t latex mwe.md -o mwe.tex
```

You will note that the LaTeX file `mwe.tex` is perfect, except because the package `actuarialangle` is not loaded at all.

If you pay attention to how RStudio run pandoc, you will see that it is because it add many options, but the relevant is:

```
--include-in-header /tmp/foo.html
```

So, you can allow to Rstudio to do this for you, or you can make `foo.html` yourself an run `pandoc` with this option, or better, change a bit the YAML header:

```
---
title: "Using more LaTeX packages"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
header-includes:
- \usepackage{actuarialangle}
---
$$ \actuarialangle{n} $$
```

This can be converted just using

```
pandoc -s -f markdown -t latex mwe.md -o mwe.tex
```

What will never will work is  compile  markdowm + LaTeX or markdowm + YALM header to PDF or HTML with others converters that only expect standard markdown syntax (e.g.,`wkhtmltopdf`).